# Вывод в виджет Activity из другого класса

Tags: java, android

Помогите с пониманием вопроса.

Есть **MainActivity**:

```
package ru.homeinn.iottank;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ConnectionMqtt connection = new ConnectionMqtt();
private Button mbtnmqtt;
public TextView mtext_mqtt;
private String NewString;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onSettingsMenuClick(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConfActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    connection.connect();

    mbtnmqtt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmqtt);
    mtext_mqtt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_text);


    mbtnmqtt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Onclick");
            connection.send();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

И есть **ConnectionMqtt**:

```
package ru.homeinn.iottank;

/**
 * Created by vit-j on 15.02.2017.
 */

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

public class ConnectionMqtt implements MqttCallback {
    MqttClient sampleClient = null;

    public ConnectionMqtt(){

    }

    public void connect(){
        try {
            String broker       = "tcp://m13.cloudmqtt.com:17546";
            String clientId     = "JavaSample";


            MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

            sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, persistence);

            sampleClient.setCallback(new ConnectionMqtt());

            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
            connOpts.setUserName("");
            connOpts.setPassword("".toCharArray());
            System.out.println("Connecting to broker: "+broker);
            sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
            System.out.println("Connected");

            //System.out.println("Message published");
            sampleClient.subscribe("#");

            //sampleClient.disconnect();
            //System.out.println("Disconnected");
            //System.exit(0);
        } catch(MqttException me) {
            //System.out.println("reason "+me.getReasonCode());
            //System.out.println("msg "+me.getMessage());
            //System.out.println("loc "+me.getLocalizedMessage());
            //System.out.println("cause "+me.getCause());
            // System.out.println("excep "+me);
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MQTTService";


    public void send(){
        int qos             = 2;
        String topic        = "MQTT Examples";
        String content      = "Message from MqttPublishSample";
        System.out.println("Publishing message: "+content);
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
        message.setQos(qos);

        try {
            sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("connectionLost!");
    }


    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Received message: "+topic + " message: " + mqttMessage);

        //mtext_mqtt.setText("Received message: "+topic + " message: " + mqttMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        System.out.println("deliveryComplete: "+iMqttDeliveryToken);

    }



}
```

В `ConnectionMqtt` нужно по получению сообщения `messageArrived` обрабатывать полученные сообщения и выводить их в текстовые поля или менять значения визуальных компонентов в `MainActivity`.

Хотя бы так:

```
mtext_mqtt.setText("Received message: "+topic + " message: " + mqttMessage);
```

Но как правильно объявить `mtext_mqtt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_text)` и передать в него данные не совсем понимаю. Как я понял этот класс не часть `Activity`

Вразумите в каком направлении двигаться и как правильно объявить.

Добавил стек трейс:

```
02-18 02:37:58.690 16678-16678/ru.homeinn.iottank E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {ru.homeinn.iottank/ru.homeinn.iottank.MainActivity}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {ru.homeinn.iottank/ru.homeinn.iottank.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onStop()
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:2937)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {ru.homeinn.iottank/ru.homeinn.iottank.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onStop()
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:4610)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:2934)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Дополнение:**

Не падает теперь, но почему то здесь:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    connection.setMqttListener(new ConnectionMqtt.MqttListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMessageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) {
            // Здесь можете работать с полученным сообщением
            System.out.println("Done!!!");
        }
    });
}
```

И здесь:

```
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Received message: "+topic + " message: " + mqttMessage);
    if (mMqttListener != null) {
        mMqttListener.onMessageArrived(topic, mqttMessage);
        System.out.println("Done1");
    }
}
```

в System сообщение Done не выводится.

Comment: Ну, как вариант, думаю, можно сделать ConnectionMqtt внутренним классом активности. Тогда у ConnectionMqtt будет доступ к её элементам.

Comment: Android studio грубо говоря, текстовый редактор, а новичок вы в java, в данном случае. Это как пытатся написать правильно предложение на французком, а когда не получается, говорить "помогите правильно написать по французки, я новичок в Блокноте"

Comment: @pavlofff Я и не спорю. Но я при этом стараюсь прочитать и осмыслить то, что мне советуют или объясняют. А не просто вставить это в код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил Callback в MainActivity:

```
connection.setCallback( new MqttCallback(){


            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("connectionLost!");
            }


            @Override
            public void messageArrived(final String topic, final MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Received message: "+topic + " message: " + mqttMessage);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        switch(topic) {
                            case "iot/light":
                                //mtext_mqtt.setText("light");
                                break;
                            case "iot/filter":
                                //mtext_mqtt.setText("filter");
                                break;
                            case "iot/compressor":
                                //mtext_mqtt.setText("compressor");
                                break;
                        }
                        //mtext_mqtt.setText("Received message: "+topic + " message: " + mqttMessage);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
                System.out.println("deliveryComplete: "+iMqttDeliveryToken);

            }
        });
```

В ConnectionMqtt:

```
public class ConnectionMqtt {

    MqttClient sampleClient = null;
```

...

```
 public void setCallback(MqttCallback cb){
        sampleClient.setCallback(cb);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

В классе `ConnectionMqtt` объявляете интерфейс `MqttListener`:

```
public interface MqttListener {
    void onMessageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage);
}
```

там же определяете поле для объекта, реализующего этот интерфейс:

```
private MqttListener mMqttListener;
```

и сеттер/ресеттер к нему:

```
public void setMqttListener(MqttListener mqttListener) {
    mMqttListener = mqttListener;
}

public void resetMqttListener() {
    mMqttListener = null;
}
```

В соответствующем коллбэке вызываете созданный коллбэк:

```
@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
    if (mMqttListener != null) {
        mMqttListener.onMessageArrived(topic, mqttMessage);
    }
}
```

в методе `onStart()` активити устанавливаете листнер:

```
connection.setMqttListener(new ConnectionMqtt.MqttListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) {
                // Здесь можете работать с полученным сообщением
            }
        });
```

в методе `onStop()` активити отвязываете листнер:

```
connection.resetMqttListener();
```

*Моменты, в которые необходимо устанавливать/отвязывать листнер зависят от конкретной ситуации.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Добавил все как вы сказали. Но через какое то время вылетает и добавил: public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Received message: "+topic + " message: " + mqttMessage);
        if (mMqttListener != null) {
            mMqttListener.onMessageArrived(topic, mqttMessage);
            System.out.println("Done1");
        }
    }  - не выводит Done1 по получению сообщения.

Comment: `Но через какое то время вылетает` – покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: добавил стек-трейс в шапку основного сообщения.

Comment: @Виталий, Добавьте в метод `onStop()` вызов аналогичного метода суперкласса: `super.onStop()`.

Comment: Добавил, не вылетает, но почему то onMessageArrived(topic, mqttMessage); не вызывается.

Comment: @Виталий, а Вы уверены, что этот метод не вызывается? Попробуйте поставить брейкпоинты и посмотреть, срабатывают ли они.

Comment: Пробовал в конец onCreate - То же самое. В onSrart оставлял только super.onStart.

Comment: Тогда могу посоветовать пройтись по коду отладчиком.

Comment: if (mMqttListener != null) { - проскакивает дальше. Видимо null

Comment: mMqttListener = mqttListener; - тут null если отладчиком смотреть

Comment: А если закомментровать //if (mMqttListener != null) {
            mMqttListener.onMessageArrived(topic, mqttMessage);
            System.out.println("Done1");
       // }  выдает ConnectionLost

Comment: @post_zeew, РеЗеттер